# Logical truth and its premises.

Tags: logic

I read the defenition of logical truth as:

> A logical truth is a sentence that is a logical consequence of any set
>   of premises. That is, no matter what the premises may be, it is
>   impossible for the conclusion to be false.

Does it matter if the premises are true or not since the conclusion cannot be false?

For example:

> Premise: All rats can fly to space
>
> Conclusion: I live on earth

Would this be a logical truth? Does the premis not have to be connected with the conclusion? It's a bit confusing.

What about:

> Premise: Some birds can fly
>
> Conclusion: I live on earth

What confuses me is this bit:

> That is, no matter what the premises may be, it is impossible for the
>   conclusion to be false.

Any clearcut examples would be nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

- All hilps are gleenish.
- All darfs are hilps.

One can conclude from these two premises that all darfs are gleenish.

That's an example on a different end:  The statements use complete nonsense words, but the conclusion is logically true, given the premises.

The statements you made -- all four of them -- could all be true, but the conclusions don't follow logically from the premises.  There's nothing to say how rats flying into space has anything to do with you living on earth.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks a ton for giving an example like this!